# If-statement does not work inside Arrow-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, arrow-functions

```
$('#title').keyup( () => {
    const title_val = $(this).val();
    console.log('before');
    if (title_val.length >= 20){
        console.log(title_val);
    }
    console.log('after');
});
```

`console.log('before')` and `console.log('after')` works. If-statement only works if I use `function()` instead of `() => {...}`, even if the condition is satisfied. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: do ` console.log('before',  title_val  );` first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `this` operator in arrow functions, only in `function` functions..

when using `this` in an arrow function, it doesn't refer to the function scope; rather, to the parent scope (usually `window`)